# jQuery .load, with specific class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to use .load to add a button, that exists on another page, for each cell on a website.

Let's say it looks like this:

```
Lalalala
Videooooo Here
Wop wop Wop wop
```

and all of those would be links. Then if you go to each link, for example "Lalalala", you'd go to a page looking like this:

Info here, blabla. Lala

So, I tried to use:

```
$(".mainpart").append("Magnet: <div id='magneturl'>Loading download buttons..</div>");
$("#magneturl").load("zoo-s01e04-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t10975316.html");
```

And it loads fine; [image]

But if I use:

```
$(".mainpart").append("Magnet: <div id='magneturl'>Loading download buttons..</div>");
$("#magneturl").load("zoo-s01e04-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t10975316.html .magnetlinkButton");
```

It will just print Magnet:

I hope I make any kind of sense with this post.

Comment: Could you copy your returned html in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or something?

Comment: @BishopBarber http://dpaste.com/0VCX98Y

Comment: are you sure you have elements with that class?  it seems to work find for me: http://jsfiddle.net/u8xtycw7/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
$("#magneturl").load("zoo-s01e04-hdtv-x264-lol-ettv-t10975316.html .magnetlinkButton");
```

is trying to fetch the content of the page and filter it applying the jQuery selector `.magnetlinkButton`. Judging by the image you posted, the file you are loading is not an HTML page but a JSON; or maybe it is HTML, but it doesn't have any element with `class="magnetlinkButton"`.

If you are actually trying to read the property `.magnetlinkButton` from that JSON text, I'd suggest looking into [.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) instead.

Answer (score -1):

check your jquery version. here is the working example :

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <b>Projects List:</b>
    <ol id="new-projects"></ol>
    <script>
        $( "#new-projects" ).load( "/resources/load.html #projects li" );
    </script>
</body>
```